# Do we use "since" or "just" in the present perfect?

Tags: present-perfect

Which one is correct in the present perfect: *since* or *just*?

For example:

> **A**: I have been here **just** only last year.
>
> **B**: I have been here **since** only last year.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these is idiomatic.

> I have been here only since last year.
>
> I have been here just since last year.

are both idiomatic. I find the second more informal.

The collocation *just only* I find both unnatural and hard to interpret.

> I was here only just last year.

(with the simple past, not the perfect) is idiomatic, but it means "it was as recently as last year that I was here", and implies that I have not been here since then.

Comment: The last example could also mean that they were "here" only just "last year", as in they weren't there before then and, quite possibly, aren't there now.

Comment: @JohnDoe: I don't find that meaning. I would find it with either "only" or "just", but not with "only just". Incidentally, I find your use of quotes quite baffling.

Comment: As a (fictitious) example, I moved to New York City about a week ago (2019 Jun 17). Before that, I lived in Atlanta, Georgia. Today, I'm in Atlanta, Georgia to tidy up a few loose ends and say goodbye to people. Say I bump into an acquaintance that I haven't seen in a long time (longer than a year ago). They ask if I live in Atlanta, Georgia. My response: "I was here (Atlanta, Georgia) only (I was never planning on being in Atlanta for a long time) just last year (from roughly 2018 Jun 17 to 2019 Jun 17)."

Comment: The quotes serve to emphasize the specific ways that those words were being used in an effort to eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting 'only' from both your examples, we have

> A: I have been here just last year.
>
> B: I have been here since last year.

If you're talking about your last visit to a place you're currently in (assumed since you use the word 'here'), A would be incorrect. Your previous visit was completed in the past, and so the correct tense would be "I was here just last year." This would apply even for a shorter time frame e.g. "I was here just yesterday" if you're talking about a visit you completed the previous day. You being in the same place now is a *repetition*, and not a continuation, of the last visit.

In the context of repeated actions, the present perfect tense would come into play in a sentence denoting multiple visits in the past, such as, "I have been here so many times!"

If, however, you're talking about an ongoing stay, B would be correct. It could mean that you moved to this place last year, and have been here even since. "I have been here since 2 pm" could mean that you've arrived at a place and have been there for a few hours. The key is that it is an action that started in the past and is *continuing*.